# PLSQL Function with For Loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following plsql code is for finding a prime number.
Whenever I run this code, I am getting following message:

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error**

```
create or replace function pf (x in number)
    return varchar2(25)
as 
    f varchar2(25);
begin
    for i in 2..round(sqrt(x))
    loop
        if x mod i = 0 then
            f := 'Is not a prime.';
        else 
            f := 'Is a prime.';
        end if;
    end loop;

    return f;
end pf;
/
```

Comment: when I run this code in Oracle Live I get Errors: FUNCTION PF
Line: 2 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
...`  so I recommend either you find out why you can't see this error message in you environment and repair this or you you create an account at https://livesql.oracle.com and make there your experiments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ishando noted, you cannot specify precision for PL/SQL parameters including the return type of a function.

Also, you should exit the loop the first time `x mod i = 0`.

```
create or replace function pf (x in number)
    return varchar2
as 
    f varchar2(25);
begin
    for i in 2..round(sqrt(x))
    loop
        if x mod i = 0 then
            f := 'Is not a prime.';
            return f;
        else 
            f := 'Is a prime.';
        end if;
    end loop;

    return f;
end pf;
```

Gives:

```
select rownum, pf(rownum) from dual connect by rownum <= 20;
```

```
    ROWNUM PF(ROWNUM)
---------- ---------------
         1
         2
         3 Is a prime.
         4 Is not a prime.
         5 Is a prime.
         6 Is not a prime.
         7 Is a prime.
         8 Is not a prime.
         9 Is not a prime.
        10 Is not a prime.
        11 Is a prime.
        12 Is not a prime.
        13 Is a prime.
        14 Is not a prime.
        15 Is not a prime.
        16 Is not a prime.
        17 Is a prime.
        18 Is not a prime.
        19 Is a prime.
        20 Is not a prime.

20 rows selected.
```

If you encounter compilation errors, any decent development tool such as [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) or [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) will automatically highlight them in the code window. Alternatively, you can get them from a query such as:

```
select e.line, e.position, e.text
from   user_errors e
where  e.name = 'PF'
and    e.attribute = 'ERROR'
order by e.sequence;
```

Or, in SQL*Plus you can use `show errors` immediately after compiling, or `show errors function pf` at any time.

Edit: to make the code slightly neater, you could default `f` to `'Is a prime'` at the start, and then only set to `'Is not a prime'` in the loop:

```
create or replace function pf (x in number)
    return varchar2
as 
    f varchar2(25) := 'Is a prime.';
begin
    for i in 2..round(sqrt(x))
    loop
        if mod(x,i) = 0 then
            f := 'Is not a prime.';
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return f;
end pf;
```

Comment: Thanks, William for your finding. I tried to build the function after modifying as you have told. But, it returned same error like before.

Moreover, when I tried to use the function in Dual table, it provided below error:
""ORA-06575: Package or function PF is in an invalid state""

Comment: What is the exact compilation error you are getting? (Not just `ORA-24344: success with compilation error`.)

Comment: Added the exact message from compiler below:

[SQL] create or replace function pf (x in number)
        return varchar2
    as 
        f varchar2(25);
    begin
       for i in 2..round(sqrt(x))
        loop
            if x mod i = 0 then
                f := 'Is not a prime.';
                return f;
            else 
                f := 'Is a prime.';
            end if;
[Err] ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Comment: No, the compilation error. `ORA-06575: Package or function PF is in an invalid state` is just telling you it can't call a function that doesn't compile.

Comment: Any guess, why the function is compiling with error?

Comment: You tell me. What tool are you using to develop PL/SQL code in?

Comment: Navicat Premium.

Comment: Dear William,
After you asked about the tool, I tried to compile the function in sqlplus and it worked fine. So, your code is perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.
Sincere Regards.

Comment: Added note about listing compilation errors. If Navicat doesn't show them then you need a better tool for PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks, Man. It means a lot. Unfortunately, Navicat doesn't show.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
create or replace function pf(x in number)
  return varchar2
is...
```

Comment: Thanks, @ishando Sir for your response. But, the the same error is still showing up.